# Duplicate/Export Permissions of entire file system

Tags: permissions, filesystems, aws

I was making a few modifications as root user on my server today and accidentally ran

`chown -R user:user /` instead of `chown -R user:user .`

I noticed quickly, but not fast enough to stop some of the directories from being changed.

I have a backup of the entire file system as a AWS EBS Snapshot, but it would take a long time to update everything to where my current system is.

The permissions haven't changed though.

Is there any way to copy the permissions of the entire file system from the backup and apply it to my current instance?

I'm running Amazons version of Linux.

Comment: We would need to know how you've taken a backup in order to recommend a way of restoring just the metadata. (You will need to restore permissions too, because SUID/SGID bits get reset by `chown`.)

Comment: @roaima Backup is AWS EBS Snapshot

Comment: Then I'm sorry I have no idea

Comment: Assuming that your "backup" is available as a filesystem, mounted at `/mnt/backup`, you could run `sudo find /mnt/backup -print0 | xargs -0 -r sudo stat --format="%a %A %F %u:%g %N"` to get a list of all the files, directories, soft links, etc., and their characteristics.

Comment: Could you give us an idea what "AWS EBS Snapshot" is? Can you mount it as a plain filesystem? Your problem can be easily solved this way otherwise you have to probably run `chown -R 0.0 /` `chown user:user /home/user` and then fix some (not all) `/var` directories' ownership. In most Linux distros only files in `/var` `/home` and `/tmp` belong to users other than root.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It is mountable storage. It is an old duplicate of the entire file system. I will try this

Comment: Tell us in the question it's mountable storage. That turns your question into "_I have a backup of my system mounted on `/mnt`. How can I use it to fix broken ownerships and permissions for my system directories?_", which is a relatively easy question to answer

Comment: Also, perhaps, include OS in case you have installed new software etc. since last snapshot. (`uname -a`)